# What's the correct math to fade a color?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, colors

I'm trying to fade a color, let's say `Yellow` to `White` over a period of time. I've got the timer worked out, and I'm applying the new color just fine as well, but the fade isn't smooth **(e.g. it fades into some weird colors before it gets to `White`, some of which are darker than their predecessor on the "fade chain" let's call it)**. I'm confident that's because the math is wrong, but I just can't seem to find a good example of the math for me to modify what I'm doing.

I even pulled the basics of the `ColorCeiling` code from this question: [Fade a color to white (increasing brightness)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710902/fade-a-color-to-white-increasing-brightness?rq=1)

Right now I take a color, and call an extension method `Increase`:

```
dataGridViewResults.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor.Increase(50);

public static Color Increase(this Color color, byte offset)
{
    return Color.FromArgb(
        color.A.ColorCeiling(offset),
        color.R.ColorCeiling(offset),
        color.G.ColorCeiling(offset),
        color.B.ColorCeiling(offset));
}
```

and as you can see, each color is then modified by an offset with a ceiling in mind to keep exceptions from being thrown. That extension method, `ColorCeiling` looks like this:

```
public static int ColorCeiling(this byte val, byte modifier, byte ceiling = 255)
{
    return (val + modifier > ceiling) ? ceiling : val + modifier;
}
```

Now, I'm confident that `ColorCeiling` is the problem, but I honestly just can't find the math. I honestly feel like just incrementing the ARGB is almost certainly the wrong approach, it seems like you'd say I want you to be 50% lighter, but I just don't know what that means as far as code.

Comment: What are the ARGB values of the colors it is along the way?

Comment: As an aside, your `ColorCeiling` method can be simplified to: `return Math.Min(val + modifier, ceiling);`, but it looks like it's functioning just fine.

Comment: @TimS., regarding the values, since I start with `Yellow` (255,255,255,0), the only value that really changes over time is the `B`. So it will increment by `50` over time. And thanks for the tip on the `return`, that's better.

Comment: Similar Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141855/programmatically-lighten-a-color

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Have you checked the actual values to see if they match what you said? What you said about the numbers is what I'd expect, but the colors you describe do not match this.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011832/generate-color-gradient-in-c-sharp ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an idea that might work.

Don't do the math in Red-Green-Blue space.  Instead treat your colour as having three components:

- Hue (is it red, orange, yellow, green, blue, violet, etc),
- Saturation (how intense is the color?)
- Value (how much blackness is in the color?)

There are algorithms for converting from RGB to HSV; look them up.  This is a good place to start:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV

Now when you are fading from one color to the other, take steps along the HSV axes, not along the RGB axes.

Comment: As a general solution I agree with you, but for a simple fade from yellow (FF FF 00) to white (FF FF FF), would this actually be any different, let alone cause as big problems as he's seeing?

Comment: I like this answer. (+1) It presents an option that feels more conceptually consistent with the desired color shift -- though, it should be noted that RGB <-> HSV conversions are "lossy."

Comment: This is a bad recommendation. Interpolating in hue space gives more colors than necessary. For example, interpolating red -> cyan will give red -> yellow -> green -> cyan. Not to mention that one need to be careful, and interpolate hue circularly (I mean, interpolating 10 to 350 need to be done with crossing zero). Using CIELAB is a much better colorspace for interpolation. Or even a simple linear interpolation in linear RGB space is better.

Answer (score 2):

A gradient is what you're looking for. YOu'll have to seperate them and recombine them like so..

```
int rMax = Color.Yellow.R;
int rMin = Color.White.R;
int bMax = Color.Yellow.B;
int bMin = Color.White.B;
int gMax = Color.Yellow.G;
int gMin = Color.White.G;

var colorList = new List<Color>();
for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    var rAverage = rMin + (int)((rMax - rMin) * i / size);
    var bAverage = bMin + (int)((bMax - bMin) * i / size);
    var gAverage = gMin + (int)((gMax - gMin) * i / size);

    colorList.Add(Color.FromArgb(rAverage, gAverage, bAverage));
}
```

Comment: If you're going to copy an answer, at least [credit the source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2011839/334849)

Answer (score 1):

Percentage implies multiplication, not addition. In my [really simple JavaScript Color class](http://www.thepointless.com/js/color.js), I do this sort of thing by defining two colors and blending the RGB dimensions.

From my Color class:

```
this.getBlendedColor = function(color, percent) {
    // limit percent between 0 and 1.
    // this percent is the amount of 'color' rgb components to use
    var p = percent > 0 ? percent : 0;
    p = p < 1 ? p : 1;

    // amount of 'this' rgb components to use
    var tp = 1 - p;

    // blend the colors
    var r = Math.round(tp * this.r + p * color.r);
    var g = Math.round(tp * this.g + p * color.g);
    var b = Math.round(tp * this.b + p * color.b);

    // return new color object
    return new Color(r, g, b);
} // getBlendedColor ()
```

So, if you had some Color c, and you wanted to get it 50% whiter, you'd do this:

```
var newColor = c.getBlendedColor(new Color('#ffffff'), 0.50);
```

If you're using the alpha channel, it can be explicitly included without causing any trouble -- both colors in you example are probably at 100% opacity.

An example gradient using simple RGB Color blending math: http://jsfiddle.net/2MymY/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code I use to fade from one color to another in the RGB color space. It works quite well for my purposes. You might have to adapt it to return the colors in steps. Currently for each `i` you will have a `curClr` that is `i/discreteUnits` percent between `baseClr` and `fadeTo`.

```
int discreteUnits = 10;
Color fadeTo = Color.Green;
Color baseClr = Color.Red;
float correctionFactor = 0.0f;
float corFactorStep = 1.0f / discreteUnits;

for(int i = 0; i < discreteUnits; i++)
{
    correctionFactor += corFactorStep;
    float red = (fadeTo.R - baseClr.R) * correctionFactor + baseClr.R;
    float green = (fadeTo.G - baseClr.G) * correctionFactor + baseClr.G;
    float blue = (fadeTo.B - baseClr.B) * correctionFactor + baseClr.B;
    Color curClr = Color.FromArgb(baseClr.A, (int)red, (int)green, (int)blue);
}
```

Credit to this site for giving me a starting place: http://www.pvladov.com/2012/09/make-color-lighter-or-darker.html